# Cannot type text in texbox that calls keydown method in knockoutjs?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have html:

```
<textarea class="textarea-custom" rows="2" data-bind="event:{keypress: function(data, e){$root.addReply(data, $parent.ID, e)}} "></textarea>
```

and JS:

```
var viewModel = {
  addReply: function(data, ID, event){
    event.keyCode === 13 && viewModel.addReplyDiscussion(data, ID, event);
    return true;
},
addReplyDiscussion : function(data, ID, event){
   //code here
}

}
```

The problem I am having is that I am unable to write any text in any of the textboxes that calls the javascript method keypress.
From what I can understand is the method is being called eveytime there is a key press and this is preventing me from being able to write anything in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you attach a handler to it, Knockout prevents the default action of an event, which in the case of `keypress` is adding the character to the field. To tell KO not to do that, `return true` from your handler.

Your `addReply` is returning `true`, but your *handler* is not, because the function you're wrapping around `addReply` is the handler. So add `return` to your wrapper:

```
data-bind="event:{keypress: function(data, e){return $root.addReply(data, $parent.ID, e);}} "
Here -----------------------------------------^
```

See "Note 3: Allowing the default action" [in the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html).